# Problem about the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{n^5+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We are given the following infinite sum,

$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ n^5+1 }  } $$

The following is true for the series,$$\frac { n }{ n^{ 5 }+1 } \le \frac { 1 }{ n^{ 4 } }$$

i) It is now given that for every $n\in N $, the following applies,

$$\sum _{ n=N+1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^{ 4 } }  } \le \frac { 4 }{ 3 } \frac { 1 }{ (N+1)^{ 3 } } $$

Using the two above equations, find the value for N such that

$$\sum _{ n=N+1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ n^{ 5 }+1 }  } \le 0.05$$

(ii) Use the result found in (iii) to determine the sum of the following serie with an error of max 0.05.
$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ n^5+1 }  } $$

**My Approach on the questions**

My book is very bad in explaining how to solve this, but I have given it the following try.

i) To find the value of N, I used the following statement/formula,

$$f(N+1)\le \epsilon$$

Where I have said that my function will be,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^4}$$
therefore
$$f(N+1)=\frac{1}{(N+1)^4}$$

Now I used the inequality,
$$\frac{1}{(N+1)^4}\le \epsilon$$

$$(N+1)^4 \ge \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
Hence,
$$N\ge 2.114742$$ meaning $$N=2$$.

iii) Now to find the sum, then,
$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ 2 }{ \frac { n }{ n^{ 5 }+1 }  }$$
$$ S_n =\frac{37}{66}$$

Can someone be so kind and tell me what I have done is right or wrong. Becuse the quesion says that i have to use the above two equations/inequalities to solve it but I had no idea how to use them.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You $:)$

Comment: Please do not repost [the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960808/about-the-series-sum-n-geq-1-fracnn51). Instead, edit the original question to add the relevant context and/or your work on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the preceding results as follows
$$
0<\sum _{n=N+1}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{n^5+1}}< \sum _{n=N+1}^{\infty}{\frac1{n^4}}\le \frac43\frac1{(N+1)^3}, \quad N\ge1,
$$ then, using
$$
\frac43\frac1{(N+1)^3}\le 0.05 \implies N\ge 2
$$ one gets that
$$
0<\sum _{n=\color{red}{2}+1}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{n^5+1}}\le 0.05
$$ and
$$
0<\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{n^5+1}}-\left(\frac{1}{1^5+1}+\frac{2}{2^5+1}\right)=\sum _{n=\color{red}{3}}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{n^5+1}}\le 0.05
$$ or

> $$
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{n^5+1}}=\frac{37}{66}+\varepsilon
> $$ with $|\varepsilon|\le0.05$.